# iOS Paypal Mobile SDK - Proof of Payment

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-mobile-sdk

i integrated the Paypal Mobile SDK for iOS in my App.

In the delegate Methode completePayment i get this json:

```
CurrencyCode: EUR
Amount: 39.95
Short Description: Michaels Test
Intent: sale
Processable: Already processed
Display: €39.95
Confirmation: {
    client =     {
        environment = mock;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.12.3";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    response =     {
        "create_time" = "2015-10-29T13:18:02Z";
        id = "PAY-NONETWORKPAYIDEXAMPLE123";
        intent = sale;
        state = approved;
    };
    "response_type" = payment;
}
Details: (null)
Shipping Address: (null)
Invoice Number: (null)
Custom: (null)
Soft Descriptor: (null)
BN code: (null)
```

It says successfully created. But when look at my dashboard in developer.paypal.com i can't see any transactions. 
For environment i use the paypal-sandbox.

In the documentation it says i have to use the rest-api to verify the immediate payment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

So do i need a backendservice that verifies my payment that was created from the client or what do i have to do at this point?

Thx,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login with your Sandbox Account here... [Sandbox Paypal Site](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/home.). You will be able to see transactions made on Sandbox Envirronment on sandbox site of the paypal.

Looking at your confirmation message, you are running your app in `PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork` mode.

```
/// Production (default): Normal, live environment. Real money gets moved.
/// This environment MUST be used for App Store submissions.
extern NSString *const PayPalEnvironmentProduction;
/// Sandbox: Uses the PayPal sandbox for transactions. Useful for development.
extern NSString *const PayPalEnvironmentSandbox;
/// NoNetwork: Mock mode. Does not submit transactions to PayPal. Fakes successful responses. Useful for unit tests.
extern NSString *const PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork;
```

You need to run your app in `SandBox` Environment. Get `YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX` and initialize your `PayPal` with it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX"}];
  return YES;
}
```

You will then be able to see transactions in the above linked site.

Comment: I know but there are no transactions so I'm wondering why there is none. My App says payment completed. So do i have to do further steps after the one i described above?

Comment: Thx seems like that was the solution i was looking for. But now i get an Internal Server Failure when i try to log in: PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR - Systemfehler. Versuchen Sie es später noch einmal. (500) | PayPal Debug-ID: daef14f8f849c [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.12.3].... i opened an Issue in iOS Paypal Mobile SDK on Github, hopefully they fix fix it soon.

Comment: Hello @EckMich , I have seen your query and I am stuck on same point. I know it's been too long though, I really want to know, did you get any workaround for this problem ? I am also getting (500 error on sandbox account). It will be much appreciated. Thanks.